# Database connectivity error? Using Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to run tests using Rspec in test environment but my database is empty, apparently when I run my db:seed command it shows

```
> $ rake RAILS_ENV=test db:seed 
> Warning: method `create` already defined
> Warning: method `update` already defined   
environment -->   1.050000 > 0.240000   1.290000 (  1.506180)   
db:load_config -->   0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.009816)   
db:abort_if_pending_migrations -->   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.030057)
db:seed -->   1.070000   0.250000   1.320000 (  1.547370)
```

If I check my seeds file its all empty. Let's say I created database with Coin in it and if I run it like this:

```
> $ rails c Running via Spring preloader in process 4229 Loading test
> environment (Rails 5.1.4) 
[1] pry(main)> Coin.all   Coin Load (0.5ms) 
> SELECT "coins".* FROM "coins"
> => []
```

There is nothing in it. Whatever I run let's say

```
$ rake db:migrate
Warning: method `create` already defined
Warning: method `update` already defined
  environment -->   1.030000   0.200000   1.230000 (  1.409833)
  db:load_config -->   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009251)
  db:schema:dump -->   0.020000   0.010000   0.030000 (  0.150969)
  db:_dump -->   0.020000   0.010000   0.030000 (  0.151114)
  db:migrate -->   0.040000   0.020000   0.060000 (  0.219740)
```

That's all I get.

How it suppose to look like is :

```
$ rails c
Warning: method `create` already defined
Warning: method `update` already defined
Running via Spring preloader in process 3940
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
[1] pry(main)> Coin.all
  Coin Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "coins".* FROM "coins"
=> [#<Coin:0x007ff5313aa4e8
  id: 1,
  coin_id: "btc",
  display_name: "Bitcoin",
  price_btc: "1",
```

But it's only working in development environment. And I wanna make it work in test environment. I will really appreciate all the suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run seed rake task from the `spec_helper.rb` or whatever you're using, here is an example:

```
YOU_AWESOME_APP::Application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
```